# Knockout: How can we move a bound div container with knockout handlers to another div dynamically?

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm facing some sort of problem with knockout

Here is the code in which I've used KO binding... now the problem which am facing is on windows/document resize I've to show this dialog box as page on mobile view. I've to move the "jobDialog" div from body to an another div. Doing that on window resize function breaks the ko binding... All the handlers attached to it stops working. So, on window resize how can i make the ko handlers keep working... (two ko custom handlers are knockout-Select2 and knockout-Jquery-UI-Spinner) ...

Thanks in Advance for the help :)

```
<!-- Job Dialog -->
<div id="cboxOverlay"></div>
<div class="main-container jobDialogBox" id="jobDialog" style="display: none;">         
<div class="layaway-dialog-main jobDialog">
    <div id="btnClose" class="cboxClose"><img src="images/close_button.png" alt="" /></div>
    <h5><strong data-bind="text: Title"></strong></h5>        
    <div class="layaway-dialog">
        <div class="Job-Dialog-Main" data-bind="foreach: Items">
            <div class="layaway-dialog-inside">
                <div data-bind="if: Type=='Select'">
                    <div class="job-dialog-row">
                        <div class="job-dialog-left"><label data-bind="text: Text"></label><span>:</span></div>
                        <div class="job-dialog-right">
                            <span class="required" data-bind="if: $data.Mandatory=='true' ">*</span>
                            <select data-bind="options: Option, optionsValue: 'Value', optionsText: 'Text', value: Value"></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="if: Type=='Input'">
                    <div class="job-dialog-row">
                        <div class="job-dialog-left"><label data-bind="text: Text"></label><span>:</span></div>
                        <div class="job-dialog-right"><span class="required" data-bind="if: $data.Mandatory=='true' ">*</span><input type="text" data-bind="value: Value" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="if: Type=='Checkbox'">
                    <div class="job-dialog-row">
                        <div class="job-dialog-left"><label data-bind="text: Text"></label><span>:</span></div>
                        <div class="job-dialog-right job-check">
                            <span class="required" data-bind="if: $data.Mandatory=='true' ">*</span>
                            <input id="jobid" type="checkbox" data-bind="value: Value, checked: $root.isCreateLayaway" />
                            <label for="jobid"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>              
                </div>
                <!-- ko if: $root.isCreateLayaway -->
                <div data-bind="if: Type=='Label'">
                    <div class="job-dialog-row">
                        <div class="job-dialog-left"><label data-bind="text: Text"></label><span>:</span></div>
                        <div class="job-dialog-right"><p data-bind="text: Value"></p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div data-bind="if: Type=='Textarea'">
                    <div class="job-dialog-row">
                        <div class="job-dialog-left"><label data-bind="text: Text"></label><span>:</span></div>
                        <div class="job-dialog-right"><span class="required" data-bind="if: $data.Mandatory=='true' ">*</span><textarea></textarea></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="if: Type=='Radio'">
                    <div class="job-dialog-row">
                        <div class="job-dialog-left"><label data-bind="text: Text"></label><span>:</span></div>
                        <div class="job-dialog-right">
                        <span class="required" data-bind="if: $data.Mandatory=='true' ">*</span>
                            <div class="job-radio" data-bind="foreach: Option">
                                <div class="job-radio-lbl">
                                    <input type="radio" data-bind="text: Text, checked:$parent.Value, attr:{'id':Id, 'name': $parent.Text, 'value': Value}" />
                                    <label data-bind="attr:{'for':Id}, text: Text"></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- Dialog Inside End -->
            <!-- ko if: !$root.isCreateLayaway() -->
             <div data-bind="if: Type=='Spinner'">
                <div class="job-bottom">
                    <div class="job-dialog-row">
                        <div class="job-dialog-left"><label data-bind="text: Text"></label><span>:</span></div>
                        <div class="job-dialog-right">
                            <!-- <span class="job-input-number"><span class="required" data-bind="if: $data.Mandatory=='true' ">*</span><input id="spinner" name="duplicate" data-bind="spinner: { value: Value, min: 1 }"></span>  -->
                            <input id="" type="number" min="1" step="1" value="1" required="true" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <div class="jobDialog-bottomicons">
            <ul>
                <!-- ko if: $root.isCreateLayaway -->
                <li><a href="#"><span class="bilkCopy"></span></a></li>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <li><a href="#"><span class="jobOk"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- End Layaway-Dialog -->
</div><!-- Layaway Dialog Main End -->
```

Comment: surely this could be achieved by simple css & responsive design? if you post a working fiddle I will make some suggestions

Comment: Moving a div will indeed break the bindings. As Tanner suggests, the ideal solution would be to not use JavaScript like this at all to achieve response design, use CSS instead. If you absolutely have to move the div, you'll need to re-apply bindings to it after you've moved it.

Comment: I've moved the div to the container where i was appending it on window resize and its working